# Creating Links To Uploaded Files (non-Image) Within Entries

Tags: channel-entries, file-uploads, file-manager

I know this may be a silly question, but since I'm new to EE, my client has a requirement of creating links within their entries to files uploaded to the file library. Since we are using the URL rewrite feature for the website, I wanted to know if there a way to link to any uploaded file, e.g.

```
<a href="link_to_file_in_filemanager.pdf">Click here</a> to download file. Blah, blah, blah....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also - for a textarea field -  set "Show file chooser" to YES. Then, when writing in that field, select some words, click on File Chooser (just below the field), select an already uploaded file (or upload a new), like a pdf.

The selected text will be linked to the file.

Comment: Magnus, thanks a million! Worked like a charm. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you'd usually do this is create a custom field in your channel, something like the native File field, or Assets, for example.

When you go to create/edit your entry, you'd upload the file through that field.

In your template, you'd reference the file using the custom field name.
`<a href="{file_custom_field_name}">Click here</a> to download file.`